# Android - bluetooth support in AVD

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-virtual-device

Is there any way to enable bluetooth on AVD running android version 2.3 or 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is [a project](https://github.com/cheng81/Android-Bluetooth-Simulator)! that should simulate what you need.

Comment: perhaps this one is meant for connection b/w AVDs only and not b/w AVD and real bluetooth devices. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK , Not Possible.

You can always go to `Window-Avd Manager - New - Hardware` and add sopports for you AVD and Bluetooth is never there.